# Sql Dynamic Query Replace Table Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

But using Replace i changed table schema after **from condition and join condition**, but one condition is failed.

Could any one help me

Example:

```
Declare @Var Nvarchar(Max)

    Set @Var='sampleid in (SELECT t1.id from EmployeesView t1 join Emp t2 t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.l5 IN (SELECT t2.id from org t2, 
    org t3,org t4 WHERE t2.l >= t3.f AND t2.l <= t3.r AND t3.id = ''40'') AND t1.lstnm = ''kc'')'


Select Replace(Replace(Convert(Varchar(Max),@Var),'from ','from AB.'),'join ','join AB.')
```

**O/P:**

```
sampleid in (SELECT t1.id from AB.EmployeesView t1 join AB.Emp t2 t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.l5 IN (SELECT t2.id from AB.org t2, 
org t3,org t4 WHERE t2.l >= t3.f AND t2.l <= t3.r AND t3.id = '40') AND t1.lstnm = 'kc')
```

**But Expected O/P:**

```
sampleid in (SELECT t1.id from AB.EmployeesView t1 join AB.Emp t2 t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.l5 IN (SELECT t2.id from AB.org t2, 
TM.org t3,TM.org t4 WHERE t2.l >= t3.f AND t2.l <= t3.r AND t3.id = '40') AND t1.lstnm = 'kc')
```

Comment: as per your que, output of @nguyen is right, what is the meaning of dynamic comes? where you stuck , explain more.

Comment: this query get for the Data base based on Login User. Each User Have different query we get. i need to add Table Schema in that query.

Comment: ok, but your question is not describe more as you want. explain more what you want, you can use variable in replace function too.

Comment: in that query find the Table names and add with schema before table names

Comment: Declare @Var Nvarchar(Max)

    Set @Var='sampleid in (SELECT t1.id from EmployeesView t1 join Emp t2 t1.id=t2.id WHERE t1.l5 IN (SELECT t2.id from org1 t2, 
    org1 t3,org t4 WHERE t2.l >= t3.f AND t2.l <= t3.r AND t3.id = ''40'') AND t1.lstnm = ''kc'')'


Select Replace(Replace(Convert(Varchar(Max),@Var),'from ','from AB.'),'join ','join AB.')

Comment: before comment i changed table name org to org1 on that time @nguyen query will not wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is Function

Create Function TM.GetSplit
(
    @SqlTxt varchar(Max)
) returns nvarchar(Max)
as
Begin
    Declare @txt nvarchar(Max),@originalTxt nvarchar(Max),@orgtxt nvarchar(max),@split nvarchar(max),@start int,@end int,@len int

```
Select @originalTxt = @SqlTxt, @orgtxt=@SqlTxt

Set @len=LEN(@orgtxt)

While @len > 0
    Begin       
        Set @len=LEN(@orgtxt)   
        Select @start=CHARINDEX('from',@orgtxt)
        Select @end=CHARINDEX('where',@orgtxt)


        If(@start != 0 and @end!=0)
            Begin
                set @split = Substring(@orgtxt, @start, @end-@start)

                Set @orgtxt = SUBSTRING(@orgtxt,@end + 5 ,@len-@end)

                Set @txt=@split

                Select @split=Replace(Replace(Replace(Convert(Varchar(Max),@split),'from ','from AB.'),'join ','join AB.') ,',',', AB.')

                Select @originalTxt=REPLACE(@originalTxt,@txt,@split)

                Set @txt=@originalTxt
            End
        Else
            Begin
                break
            End
    End

    If @txt is null
        Begin
            Select @txt=Replace(Replace(Convert(Varchar(Max),@originalTxt),'from ','from AB.'),'join ','join AB.')
        End

return @txt
```

End

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Convert(Varchar(Max),@Var),'from ','from AB.'),'join ','join AB.'), 'org', 'TM.org'), 'AB.TM', 'AB')
```

Comment: table name is dynamic comes, i need dynamically

Comment: i think nguyen's query will give you expected output. do you mean you have to pass table name as dynamic variable?